# AWS: VPN between VPC and an external resource with IKEv2 and ESP

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc, network-security

I need to set up a VPN tunnel between the VPC in AWS and an external server with content that I want to access securely. The idea is to use the Site-to-site VPN Connection with Virtual Private Gateway and a Customer Gateway. The tunnels are configured like this:

[image: aws-tunel-options]

However, the options that I would like to set are as follows:

```
Phase 1 : IKEv2 - AES256 - SHA-256 - modp3072
Phase 2 : ESP - AES256 - SHA-256 - modp3072
```

Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see the tunnels have the options you want. If you’re wondering about the last parameter ... [modp-3072 is DH Group 15](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526#section-4), same thing.

And Phase 2 is always ESP so it’s not explicitly noted (unless you’ve got some very special tunnel using AH protocol, but that’s very rare and I doubt AWS VGW supports it).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Argh, thank you for your response @MLu. I'm not an expert yet and I got confused by the answer I got from the other company when I sent them a configuration file downloaded from AWS (one the tunnel is configured, AWS lets you choose the platform/software and download the config that should be applied on the other side of the tunnel). But, apart from the PSKs and IP addresses, the config file is a default one it seems (with IKEv1 and modp1024 for example), so the other company got confused and so did I  I will see if the tunnels will be up and mark your response as answer then. Cheers!